# Join JSON array field with string field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am looking for records in table 2 whose id exist in the values of nums field (JSON) in table 1.

**table1**

```
id | nums (JSON)
---+-------------------
1  | ["1","2","3","4"]
2  | ["7","8","5","6"]
3  | ["9","10","3","4"]
```

**table2**

```
id |
---+
1  | 
2  | 
53 | 
63 |
```

I would like to get the next result.

**rows desired**

```
id |
---+
1  | 
2  |
```

I am using 5.7 mysql version.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1
    LEFT JOIN table 2 as t2 on JSON_CONTAINS(t1.id->'$[*]', CAST(t2.id as JSON))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
select t2.id
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1
              where json_contains(nums, t2.id)
             );
```

You may need to cast the second argument to a string.

Comment: this one throws an error 'The document root must not follow by other value' I added this `CAST(t2.id  as CHAR(50))` also.

Comment: @J.Ordaz: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5abRfyg6v2sPzzRsE3VuMH/0).

Comment: @wchiquito I was not using JSON_QUOTE as you do, I already tested it and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to just cast your JSON arrays to text, and then use `REGEXP` to search for matching ids:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
              WHERE CAST(t1.nums AS CHAR(50))
              REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', CAST(t2.id AS CHAR(50)), '[[:>:]]');
```

Comment: @J.Ordaz But have a look at Gordon's answer, which (I think) is the other way of doing this using pure JSON functions.