# How could I make join with column type text contains JSON array using Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to make join using column contains JSON array and column type is text.
transaction table

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | cash |
| 2 | cash |
| 3 | credit |

route_activities table

| id | transactions |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{transaction_id:"1"},{transaction_id:"2"}] |
| 2 | [{transaction_id:"2"}] |

so I was trying with these code

```php
$sale_data = DB::table('route_activities')
            ->Join('routes','routes.driver_id','=','route_activities.driver_id')
            ->Join('transactions','transactions.transaction_id',
                DB::Raw("route_activities.transactions->'$[*].transaction_id',CAST(transactions.transaction_id as JSON)")
            )
            ->selectRaw('
                route_activities.activity as activity,
                route_activities.check_in as check_in,
                route_activities.date as date,
                route_activities.check_out as check_out,
                route_activities.coordinates as coordinates,
                CASE WHEN visit_status = "Productive" THEN "true" ELSE "false" END as is_productive
            ')
            ->get();
```

and it's not working.
I get some links [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256141/join-json-array-field-with-string-field-in-mysql) and [this](https://gist.github.com/Mevrael/bc645cb63a2d3bbae3fb43366b47f313)

but all of them is not giving me what I am looking for. any help :)?

I am using Laravel-v7.30. and Mysql v5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT a.*, t.* 
FROM route_activities a
JOIN transactions t ON JSON_CONTAINS(
  JSON_EXTRACT(a.transactions, '$[*].transaction_id'), 
  JSON_QUOTE(CONVERT(t.id, char)), 
  '$'
);
```

This should yield something similar to this:

| trans_id | transactions | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"transaction_id": "1"}, {"transaction_id": "2"}] | cash |
| 1 | [{"transaction_id": "1"}, {"transaction_id": "2"}] | cash |
| 2 | [{"transaction_id": "3"}] | credit |

Seeing that you are already using `selectRaw` you can throw in the query inside a `DB::select(..)` as in:

```
DB::select("ra.activity as activity,
            ra.check_in as check_in,
            ra.date as date,
            ra.check_out as check_out,
            ra.coordinates as coordinates,
            CASE WHEN visit_status = "Productive" THEN "true" ELSE "false" END as is_productive 
            FROM route_activities ra
            JOIN transactions t ON JSON_CONTAINS(json_extract(a.transactions, '$[*].transaction_id'), json_quote(convert(t.id, char)), '$')
            JOIN routes r ON r.driver_id = ra.driver_id")
->get()
```

Considering route activities will be duplicated, I don't know if the result set is usable as is, but I hope this points you in the right direction.